# Azure Cache task produces System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No matching files found for pattern

Tags: azure-devops

I am using this example from Azure devops docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/caching-nuget?view=azure-devops

```
variables:
  NUGET_PACKAGES: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.nuget/packages

- task: Cache@2
  displayName: Cache
  inputs:
    key: 'nuget | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/packages.lock.json,!**/bin/**,!**/obj/**'
    restoreKeys: |
       nuget | "$(Agent.OS)"
       nuget
    path: '$(NUGET_PACKAGES)'
    cacheHitVar: 'CACHE_RESTORED'
```

I get this error when calling the cache task. Any idea what is wrong?

```
2023-10-30T18:10:38.7068066Z ##[section]Starting: NuGet Cache
2023-10-30T18:10:38.7210499Z ==============================================================================
2023-10-30T18:10:38.7210902Z Task         : Cache
2023-10-30T18:10:38.7211034Z Description  : Cache files between runs
2023-10-30T18:10:38.7211269Z Version      : 2.198.0
2023-10-30T18:10:38.7211412Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-10-30T18:10:38.7211625Z Help         : https://aka.ms/pipeline-caching-docs
2023-10-30T18:10:38.7211912Z ==============================================================================
2023-10-30T18:10:39.1559570Z Resolving key:
2023-10-30T18:10:39.1771434Z  - nuget                                       [string]
2023-10-30T18:10:39.1776896Z  - "Windows_NT"                                [string]
2023-10-30T18:10:39.2982850Z  - **/packages.lock.json,!**/bin/**,!**/obj/** [file pattern; matches: 0]
2023-10-30T18:10:39.3161650Z ##[error]One or several exceptions have been occurred.
2023-10-30T18:10:39.3182795Z ##[error]System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No matching files found for pattern: **/packages.lock.json,!**/bin/**,!**/obj/**
2023-10-30T18:10:39.3214721Z ##[section]Finishing: NuGet Cache
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The syntax  `**/packages.lock.json,!**/bin/**,!**/obj/**` means it will search all packages.lock.json located in a directory under the sources directory, except under the bin and obj directory. However the json file is not found and the error reported.

To set up the cache task, you need firstly lock the project's dependencies and **create a package.lock.json file**.

To lock your project's dependencies, set the RestorePackagesWithLockFile property in your csproj file to true. NuGet restore generates a lock file packages.lock.json at the root directory of your project. **Make sure you check your packages.lock.json file into your source code.**

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/caching-nuget?view=azure-devops#lock-dependencies) for the details.

My project structure for your reference:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What happens when we update our dependencies? Does this file get updated on a local source build and then get checked in with a new dependency list in it?

Comment: Also, when you have multiple projects in a solution, do you have to set this in every project and the build somehow combines all packages into this single lock file, or do you only have to set it in the top project in the dependency tree (what you are publishing) and it does it for all other projects?

Comment: @user1867382, With `RestorePackagesWithLockFile` property added, you can simply use dotnet restore(or nuget resotre) on local machine to generate the packages.lock.json file, don't need to build, and then check in the file to the DevOps repo for pipeline.

Comment: You can have one packages.lock.json for all projects to cache all, or you can also have multiple packages.lock.json files in each projects, add cache for each project to restore. But it's new query for the best practice, you can raise a new ticket and we can chat further on that one if needed :).

Comment: @user1867382, may i know if it's resolved after adding the packages.lock.json file? if it is, it's recommended to [mark the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) according to How does accepting an answer work. Thanks.

Comment: @wade-zhou-msft On first run the cache was created and stored post-build. Cache was then restored on the next build and restore step skipped due to condition. But build failed with these errors for each project: error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\Project.Domain\obj\project.assets.json' not found